# Magento - add a grid inside a form

Tags: php, magento

in magento, how can I add a grid block (extending `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid`) inside a form block (extending `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form` ).
Is there any way around this without having to use tabs?